# javascript regular expression .search

Tags: javascript, search

i have a little problem with .search

this is the code

```
// filter - posts
jQuery('.filter_by').live('click',function(){
    var target_fi = jQuery(this);
    var target_cat = target_fi.parents('.cat').children('.namechanger').val(); 
    target_fi.next().fadeIn(100);


    var cat_all = target_fi.prev().find("option").each(function(i){
        if(jQuery(this).attr('data-cats').search(target_cat)  == -1){
            jQuery(this).css({"display":"none"});
        }
    });


});
```

I want to use the variable `target_cat` with .search

I can't do this `.search(/target_cat/)`

Comment: try `new RegExp(target_cat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a regular expression out of the string value of `target_cat`, then you can do this:

```
var mySearchTerm = new RegExp(target_cat);

...

if(jQuery(this).attr('data-cats').search(mySearchTerm)  == -1){
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to declare a new variable for that.

Comment: @Amberlamps I suppose, but it highlights how it needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `RegExp` object and pass that to `search` method

```
if(jQuery(this).attr('data-cats').search(new RegExp(target_cat)) == -1 )){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert *anything* into a regular expression, simply drop it into the constructor:

var something = "foobar";
   var expression = new RegExp(something, 'i');

note the second argument for flags. See [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info on the constructor and [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for details on how things work.

If your `something` contains "special characters" (such as `|`, `?`, `{`) you need to escape them, if you want them to be meant literally (`/foo?/` vs. `/foo\?/`). Here's a function that'll esacpe all relevant characters for you:

```
function escapeRegEx(string) {
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
}
```

---

- You are using `jQuery.live`, but should use [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead
- You are using `.search()` when [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) suffices
- You are using the explicit `jQuery(this).css({"display":"none"});` when `jQuery(this).hide();` suffices
- note that you are repeating `jQuery(this)` in your loop - one should be enough - variables are your friends.